# Change cursor in VSCodeVim during insert or command mode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

Using the most excellent VSCodeVim plugin.  Is it possible to have the cursor change when in normal/command mode (block perhaps) versus input mode (vertical or underline perhaps)?

Answer (score 9):

You can add these in your setting.json or search for these terms in case of using GUI setting

```
"vim.cursorStylePerMode.insert": "line-thin",
"vim.cursorStylePerMode.normal": "block",
```

This will turn cursor to thin line in insert mode and block in normal mode, which will distinguish both easily.